# How to implement a jointplot using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a a visualisation project using d3js. I have some distributed dataset that I need to visualise like that :

[image: visualisation]

this visualisation was done using `seaborn.jointplot` in python, but I need this to be implemented using d3js, is there any alternative for that in d3js? how can this be done in d3js ?

[seaborn.jointplot API Documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html)

Comment: No, direct layout. You will have to make a scatter chart and then place the 2 bar charts along side, just as how you have put up on the image. Good Luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cool looking plot and I had some time this morning, so here's a `d3` v4 minimal implementation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 80,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20
      },
      width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain([0, 10]),
      y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, 10]);

     // Add the X Axis
    g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

     // Add the Y Axis
    g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    var random = d3.randomNormal(0, 1.2),
      data = d3.range(100).map(function() {
        return [random() + 5, random() + 5];
      });

    g.selectAll(".point")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke", "lightgray");

     // top histogram
    var gTop = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 0 + ")");

    var xBins = d3.histogram()
      .domain(x.domain())
      .thresholds(x.ticks(10))
      .value(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })(data);

    var xy = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(xBins, function(d) {
        return d.length;
      })])
      .range([margin.top, 0]);

    var xBar = gTop.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(xBins)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + xy(d.length) + ")";
      });

    var bWidth = x(xBins[0].x1) - x(xBins[0].x0) - 1;
    xBar.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 1)
      .attr("width", bWidth)
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return margin.top - xy(d.length);
      })
      .style("fill", "steelblue");

    xBar.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .attr("y", 2)
      .attr("x", bWidth / 2)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.length < 4 ? "" : d.length;
      })
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("font", "9px sans-serif");

     // right histogram
    var gRight = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + (margin.left + width) + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var yBins = d3.histogram()
      .domain(y.domain())
      .thresholds(y.ticks(10))
      .value(function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })(data);

    var yx = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(yBins, function(d) {
        return d.length;
      })])
      .range([0, margin.right]);

    var yBar = gRight.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(yBins)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + 0 + "," + y(d.x1) + ")";
      });

    var bWidth = y(yBins[0].x0) - y(yBins[0].x1) - 1;
    yBar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", 1)
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return yx(d.length);
      })
      .attr("height", bWidth)
      .style("fill", "steelblue");

    yBar.append("text")
      .attr("dx", "-.75em")
      .attr("y", bWidth / 2 + 1)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return yx(d.length);
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.length < 4 ? "" : d.length;
      })
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("font", "9px sans-serif");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

d3.js version 3 sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <style>
    .bar {
      fill: steelblue;
    }
    
    .bar:hover {
      fill: brown;
    }
    
    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 80,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20
      },
      width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]).domain([0, 10]),
      y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, 10]);

    // Add the X Axis
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom").scale(x));

    // Add the Y Axis
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().orient("left").scale(y));

    var random = d3.random.normal(0, 1.2),
      data = d3.range(100).map(function() {
        return [random() + 5, random() + 5];
      });

    g.selectAll(".point")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke", "lightgray");

    // top histogram
    var gTop = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 0 + ")");

    var xBins = d3.layout.histogram()
      .range(x.domain())
      .bins(x.ticks(10))
      .value(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })(data);

    var xy = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(xBins, function(d) {
        return d.length;
      })])
      .range([margin.top, 0]);

    var xBar = gTop.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(xBins)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + xy(d.length) + ")";
      });

    var bWidth = x(xBins[0].dx) - 1;
    xBar.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 1)
      .attr("width", bWidth)
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return margin.top - xy(d.length);
      })
      .style("fill", "steelblue");

    xBar.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .attr("y", 2)
      .attr("x", bWidth / 2)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.length < 4 ? "" : d.length;
      })
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("font", "9px sans-serif");

    // right histogram
    var gRight = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + (margin.left + width) + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var yBins = d3.layout.histogram()
      .range(y.domain())
      .bins(y.ticks(10))
      .value(function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })(data);

    console.log(yBins);

    var yx = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(yBins, function(d) {
        return d.length;
      })])
      .range([0, margin.right]);

    var yBar = gRight.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(yBins)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + 0 + "," + y(d.x + d.dx) + ")";
      });

    yBar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", 1)
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return yx(d.length);
      })
      .attr("height", bWidth)
      .style("fill", "steelblue");

    yBar.append("text")
      .attr("dx", "-.75em")
      .attr("y", bWidth / 2 + 1)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return yx(d.length);
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.length < 4 ? "" : d.length;
      })
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("font", "9px sans-serif");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, You're a star, works like a charm, I wish I could double vote up :)

Comment: can you please help with this..
I'm trying to use the code you provided for my nba shot chart, but I'm stuck, for some reason the right bars don't look good. http://jmargieh.github.io/NBA-shots-chart-d3js/
see this as well http://savvastjortjoglou.com/nba-shot-sharts.html, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JayMar, that's just too much code to wade through.  Can you throw just the jointplot **with some real data** into a jsFiddle or Plunker?

Comment: thanks for you comment, here you go, http://jsbin.com/lofaqozozu/1/edit?html,output , I hope that's better now

Comment: I put some real data showing just the chart, I've been trying to integrate your solution with the points on my chart but I haven't succeed, I hope you could help me with that or guide me through it.
I really appreciate your help, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JayMar I am traveling next few days. I will take a look on Monday.  Let me know if you sort it out before then.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll keep trying and update you, have a safe trip :)

Comment: @JayMar, I'm not sure I understand the data.  How does the yScale map to the court dimensions.  There's a lot of *magic* numbers in your code that'll make it impossible to scale things correctly when you add margins.  For example, things like `.domain([-1, 0, -150]).range([590, 589, 371]);` and `return (d[16] > 45 ? 0 : yScale(-d[18]));` need to be written out as calculations on chart height, otherwise you'll never to able to adjust things...

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for your comment, yes you are right I noticed that, please take a look at this : http://jmargieh.github.io/NBA-shots-chart-d3js/
I've managed to solve the right histogram problem, but for some how the margins aren't right, and I can't get it to display more bars.

Comment: @JayMar, I think the biggest disconnect between my work above and yours this that you are attempting to *bin* your data using the **pixel** values of data.  In my work above, I bin using the **user** space values. If you want to bin pixel values, this is completely valid, but you on longer need scales to position the bars.  The histogram data will contain the pixel locations.  [See new example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IrgweE14tpqNLJTIBHDW?p=preview).

Comment: @JayMar, in addition, I did a bit of work to make the charts position appropriately regardless of height/width.  I did this rather hacky by scaling your magic numbers by percentages.  It seems to work but without know how the court dimensions map to those x/y values in your JSON, it feels like we are just guessing.