# Adding jointplot to NBA shot chart using d3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to add a jointplot to a NBA shot chart,

**so it would look like this :**

[image]

The problem is that I can't get the bars to work properly, and I really don't know why this is happening.

It would be great if, someone guides me what do I have to change in the jointplot in order to work with the NBA chart.

**NBA shot chart :**

[http://jsbin.com/guqiviniji/edit?html,output](http://jsbin.com/jodebotajo/1/edit?html,output)

**Jointplot implementation :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <style>
    .bar {
      fill: steelblue;
    }
    
    .bar:hover {
      fill: brown;
    }
    
    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 80,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20
      },
      width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]).domain([0, 10]),
      y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, 10]);

    // Add the X Axis
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom").scale(x));

    // Add the Y Axis
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().orient("left").scale(y));

    var random = d3.random.normal(0, 1.2),
      data = d3.range(100).map(function() {
        return [random() + 5, random() + 5];
      });

    g.selectAll(".point")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("r", 7)
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke", "lightgray");

    // top histogram
    var gTop = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 0 + ")");

    var xBins = d3.layout.histogram()
      .range(x.domain())
      .bins(x.ticks(10))
      .value(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })(data);

    var xy = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(xBins, function(d) {
        return d.length;
      })])
      .range([margin.top, 0]);

    var xBar = gTop.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(xBins)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + xy(d.length) + ")";
      });

    var bWidth = x(xBins[0].dx) - 1;
    xBar.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 1)
      .attr("width", bWidth)
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return margin.top - xy(d.length);
      })
      .style("fill", "steelblue");

    xBar.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .attr("y", 2)
      .attr("x", bWidth / 2)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.length < 4 ? "" : d.length;
      })
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("font", "9px sans-serif");

    // right histogram
    var gRight = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + (margin.left + width) + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var yBins = d3.layout.histogram()
      .range(y.domain())
      .bins(y.ticks(10))
      .value(function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })(data);

    console.log(yBins);

    var yx = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(yBins, function(d) {
        return d.length;
      })])
      .range([0, margin.right]);

    var yBar = gRight.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(yBins)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + 0 + "," + y(d.x + d.dx) + ")";
      });

    yBar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", 1)
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return yx(d.length);
      })
      .attr("height", bWidth)
      .style("fill", "steelblue");

    yBar.append("text")
      .attr("dx", "-.75em")
      .attr("y", bWidth / 2 + 1)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return yx(d.length);
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.length < 4 ? "" : d.length;
      })
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("font", "9px sans-serif");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, it looks ok to me. What is wrong, actually? What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: @altocumulus There's two links for jsbin, the first has the nba shot chart, and the second has a jointplot implementation, what I'm trying to do is integrating the jointplot into the nba shot chart, to get a shot chart with it's jointplot which looks like the image above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I put a lot of effort into answering this question in the comments [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676392/16363), I guess it's worth it to re-hash it as an answer on this question.

I really see two large problems with the code in the jsbin link.

First, a strong reliance on *magic* numbers.  It looks like the OP used trial and error to get the shots placed properly for a specific height/width of his chart.  This, of course, means that adding margins or changing sizes requires a lot of effort in developing new magic numbers.  I solve this reliance below by scaling the original magic numbers by percents as the chart height and width change. This is a bit of a hack but seems to work.

Second, in the original "joint plot" sample I developed, I *binned* the data using the **user-space** data. I then needed x and y scales to map the user-space bins back to pixel locations. In the OPs jsbin, though, he is using **pixel-space** data to bin the data.  This is, of course, completely valid, and in fact, is probably **better** as the placement of the bars becomes easier.  You don't need to re-introduce more scales to place them.

Finally, I did a bit more work to make the bin size adjustable.

Here's some code for the right histogram:

```
    // right histogram
    var gRight = r_svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + (margins.left + max.x) + "," + margins.top + ")");

    var m = d3.max(histogramData, function(d) { return d[1] });
    var yBins = d3.layout.histogram()
      .range([0, m])
      .bins(d3.range(0, m + 20, 20)) //<-- bin size is more adjustable, lower the 20, 20 for more bins
      .value(function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })(histogramData); //<-- data has pixel values

    var yx = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(yBins, function(d) {
        return d.length;
      })])
      .range([0, margins.right]);

    var yBar = gRight.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(yBins)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + 0 + "," + (d.x) + ")"; //<-- pixel values just place at d.x
      });

    yBar.append("rect")
      .attr("y", 1)
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return yx(d.length);
      })
      .attr("height", bWidth)
      .style("fill", "steelblue");

    yBar.append("text")
      .attr("dx", "-.75em")
      .attr("y", bWidth / 2 + 1)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return yx(d.length);
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.length < 15 ? "" : d.length;
      })
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("font", "9px sans-serif");
```

[Running code is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IrgweE14tpqNLJTIBHDW?p=preview).